# Counter for unique profile views

Tags: php, view, unique, profile

So im trying to make unique profile views, i thought of creating 2 tables in MySQL:

- `pages (id, profile_id, user_id, date)`
- `profile_views (id, profile_id, user_id, count)`

So when a user goes to a profile it will insert a new record into `profile_vies` with my `user_id` and increase the counter. Also it will insert a record in the `pages` table with my data.

The increment will start if no record of my ID and the `profile_id` is set inside the pages table within 24 hours, because every 24 hours all queries < 24 hours will be deleted so new counts will take place.

I would like your opinion on this theory on profile views... without using textfiles with IPs stored, or please if you can tell me any better thoughts on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic look fine.
When ever user visit a profile add the count of that id to the table , save the date time also.

If user visit profile again within the 24 hours find the difference between current date time and the date time you saved in the db already . if it is more than 24 hrs / 1 day dont increment the count.

Otherwise increment the count.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    //Include your database here.

    $ID = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['ID'])));


    $getUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Members WHERE ID='".$ID."'");
    $gU = mysql_fetch_object($getUser);


    if ($myU->ID != $ID) {

        if ($User) {

            mysql_query("UPDATE Members SET ProfileViews=ProfileViews + 1 WHERE ID='".$ID."'");

        }

    }

    echo "".$gU->ProfileViews."";

?>
```